# Escaping slashes in jQuery for passing paths in an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, escaping

I have a problem with slashes! I have some jQuery for handling generic dialogs on a page. In some cases the fields are passing /-delimited paths...

```
var fieldValues = [];
// pull values from all the fields belonging to the dialog...
$.each($(this).find('input, textarea, select'), function(n,field) {
  // escape the path fields
  var value = escape($(field).val().replace(/\//g,'__slash__'));
  //alert ($(field).attr('id')+'='+value);
  if(id != '' && value != '') {
    fieldValues.push(id+'='+value);
  }
});
```

This code works, but I have a manual stripping out of __slash__ when I get to the php end of things. Is there some encoding function I'm missing that would let me drop the clumsy-looking replace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Javascript's built-in [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and then PHP's [`rawurldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) should decode it in PHP once received.